# Increase space between rings in D3 ring chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am working on a ring chart with multiple concentric rings.

I would like to increase the space between the rings and the width of the rings.
Here is my working fiddle:

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/szada3/tu6d7wzc/9/][1]
```

[image: I'd like to achieve something like this]
The arrows in the right picture represents the space what I would like to increase.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a better solution.

Instead of playing with the `scale` attribute I've added

```
.attr("d", pathArc.innerRadius(60 * ((i*0.1) + 1)), pathArc.outerRadius(60 * ((i*0.1) + 1) + 10))
```

to the return of the `arcFunction`.

See the modified [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szada3/tu6d7wzc/13/)

https://jsfiddle.net/szada3/tu6d7wzc/13/

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Manipulate with `i` in `arcFunction` and `arcFunction2`:

```
.attr("transform", "scale(1." + i*3 + ")");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szada3/tu6d7wzc/9/

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the scaling in `arcFunction` to add some space between the rings (just be careful that `(i+5) < 10`)

```
.attr("transform", "scale(1." + (i+5) + ")");
```

You should also change the size of the ring like that :

```
 .outerRadius((width + 200) / 5 + 2);
```

See : https://jsfiddle.net/v1wh8y09/